# Domain of the derivative of $sec^{-1}x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My calculusbook asks:

> "**The derivative of $sec^{-1}x$ is positive for every $x$ in the domain
>   of $sec^{-1}$.** Does this imply that $sec^{-1}$ is increasing on its
>   domain? Why?"

Is that first statement (bold) really true? I thought that:

1. The domain of $sec^{-1}x$ is $|x|\ge1$
2. The derivative of $sec^{-1}x$ is $\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$
3. Therefore the derivative of $sec^{-1}x$ is not defined for $x=1$ or $x=-1$ which are part of the domain of $sec^{-1}x$

QUESTION: is the statement in my calculusbook wrong?

Comment: It may not be defined but it is still a positive number no? From your formula you can already see that the derivative always has a positive value, which is what your textbook says.

Comment: @Horus for $x=1$ the derivative is $1/0$ which isn't defined.

Comment: If you look at an inverse secant graph, it is pretty evident that the derivative is positive. 1/0 may not be defined, but it is still a positive number corresponding to an upwards straight line which fits your textbook definition.